# Построить список для синуса

Tags: python, list, numpy

Как построить список `f = []` длинной 15 и синус функцию в нем, с интервалом равное 3 и высотой 1/-1? А как построить со смещением тоже самое, например пропустив первые 5 значений в списке и обозначив их как 0?

Пример где 3 это интервал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Андрей, подтяните слегка математику, потому что сейчас вы не понимаете, что пишите.

Comment: @АндрейТи, можете пояснить на счет смещения или лучше привести эскиз того, что вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 2):

Да, внятное объяснение того чего вы хотите - явно не ваша сильная сторона. Не очень понял, чего вам надо, но то что понял -  можно попробовать сделать вот так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,15,300)
y1=np.zeros(60,dtype=float)
y2=np.sin(x[:-60])
y=np.concatenate([y1,y2])
plt.plot(x,y)
```

С результатом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно? Тут смещение на три вправо, если что.

Comment: Так я же вам пример дал. Готового решения.  Или вам отдельно привести решение для "3 или 6 или 8 или 20"?

Comment: @Андрей Ти -   Вы  понимаете, что график рисуется не по вашим "смещениям", а по гораздо большему количеству точек. Иначе вы не получите плавной линии.   Ну так пересчитайте ваше смещение на количество точек, в которое оно превращается при выводе графика.

Comment: @Андрей Ти -  такое впечатление, что вы вообще не понимаете, что я вам говорю. От слова "совсем". Вы хоть немного с Python знакомы? Скрипт  на четыре строчки. В нем реализовано смещение на три единицы по оси Х. Надо седлать  то-же но с другим смещением. Про загадочный вами придуманный термин "интервал графика" я даже не спрашиваю. А про "плавно или нет" - ну попробуйте самостоятельно построит  график по точкам 1,2,3....15 -  тогда может быть и поймете причем тут то, о чем я вам пытаюсь втолковать.

Comment: @ Андрей Ти - ну, т.е. с Python вы незнакомы и ни одного графика сами нарисовать не в состоянии. Понятно. Ответ неверный - не пользуйтесь им, но только сначала попробуйте объяснить, что-же он делает неверного относительно вопроса, который вы задали изначально.

Comment: @АндрейТи, я же вам уже показал как изменить период синусоиды в своём ответе, который вам не подошёл потому что вы не смогли внятно объяснить что вы хотите. Но в том ответе я вам показал как изменить период синусоиды - это азы из школьной тригонометрии)

Comment: @ MaxU -  у человека и без нас дел хватает, а вы хотите, что-бы он разобрался с азами школьной тригонометрии.

Comment: @passant, похоже вы правы. С азами и здесь могут помочь, а вот со внятными формулировками все гораздо сложнее) На SO катастрофически не хватает телепатов :-D